# PHP convert string variable that comes as ASCII to UTF8_unicode_ci keeping national characters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, utf-8, character-encoding

In Laravel I have to migrate data from one database on MySql to the other database.
Data from first MySQl comes as ASCII and have national characters. And I have to save this data in the second MySql database. Second database have column in UTF8_unicode_ci encoding.
Code to get data from first database:

```
$pdo = DB::connection('mysqlPDO')->getPdo();
        
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `form_data` WHERE sent_to_pbox = 0 AND LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        unset($stmt);
```

And code to save in the second database:

```
$clientAddressEntity = ClientAddress::create([
                        'client_id' => $clientEntity->id,
                        'street' => mb_convert_encoding($importDTO->street, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8'),
                        'building_no' => utf8_encode($importDTO->building_no),
                        'post_code' => utf8_encode($importDTO->post_code),
                        'city' => utf8_encode($importDTO->city),
                        'country_id' => isset($countryEntity) ? $countryEntity->id : null,
                    ]);
```

`mb_convert_encoding` and `utf8_encode` doesn't work. Polish letters like ł,ę,ą and etc are saved in database as ?
Table in the second database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `client_address` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_no` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

---

When I add:

'street' => $importDTO->street . ' ' . mb_detect_encoding($importDTO->street),

I get result: `Ja?minowa ASCII`

Comment: First of all remove `utf8_encode()`. It's likely the cause of your problems

Comment: Is your connection charset set to `utf8mb4`?

Comment: ASCII, by definition, does not have "national characters."

Comment: I think you meant the old deprecated `utf8` charset instead of ASCII. Please confirm from which charset you are migrating truly

Comment: Also see the database-specific steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) as well. Ensure the character set on your connection to both servers matches what the database is using.

Comment: When I removed `utf8_encode()` data inserted into database looks like that: Os. S?owia?skie

Comment: How can data both come as ASCII **and** have national characters. The ASCII standard  does not include any national characters so I don't think what you're getting is actually ASCII so you should first figure out what encoding you're actually getting and then convert it accordingly (if needed, most times the conversion can be done for you via the MySQL connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution, in controller I have to add set utf8:

```
  $pdo = DB::connection('mysqlPDO')->getPdo();
  $pdo->exec("set names utf8");
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM .... );
```